# Kind inference can't infer and Constraint Kinds does nothing

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-constraints, type-kinds

### tl;dr How do I get `Class` to have kind `(* -> *) -> Constraint`?

I have the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, TypeFamilies, RankNTypes, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class MonadTrans t where
    type Class t
    lift :: (Monad m) => m b -> t m b
    generalize :: (Monad m) => t m a -> (forall m'. (Class t m') => m a)

class (Monad m) => MaybeC m where
    fart :: m a

data MaybeT m a = NothingT | JustT (m a)

instance (Monad m) => Monad (MaybeT m) where
    return = JustT . return
    (JustT a) >>= f = a >>= f
    NothingT >>= f = NothingT

instance (Monad m) => MaybeC (MaybeT m) where
    fart = NothingT

instance MonadTrans MaybeT where
    type Class Maybe = MaybeC --Error Is HERE
    lift = JustT
    generalize NothingT = fart
    generalize JustT a  = return a
```

The compiler says: "`Expected kind '* -> Constraint', but`MaybeC' has kind `(* -> *) -> Constraint'</code>`" but `Class` is `(*->*)->Constraint`.

So then I tried:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, TypeFamilies, RankNTypes, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class MonadTrans t where
    type Class t :: (*->*)->Constraint
    lift :: (Monad m) => m b -> t m b
    generalize :: (Monad m) => t m a -> (forall m'. (Class t m') => m a)

class (Monad m) => MaybeC m where
    fart :: m a

data MaybeT m a = NothingT | JustT (m a)

instance (Monad m) => Monad (MaybeT m) where
    return = JustT . return
    (JustT a) >>= f = a >>= f
    NothingT >>= f = NothingT

instance (Monad m) => MaybeC (MaybeT m) where
    fart = NothingT

instance MonadTrans MaybeT where
    type Class Maybe = MaybeC
    lift = JustT
    generalize NothingT = fart
    generalize JustT a  = return a
```

But the compiler says "`pad1.hs:4:37: Not in scope: type constructor or class 'Constraint'`", so `ConstraintKinds` is doing nothing for me.

Comment: You'll need to import ``Constraint`` using ``import GHC.Exts (Constraint)``.

Comment: @Stephen Diehl I'll try that.

Comment: Also, might type a kind annotation on just t like: `type Class (t :: * -> *)`.  (Might need `KindSignatures` extension for that.)

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I fear your `Monad (MaybeT m)` instance won't work. `a >>= f` returns an `m (MaybeT m b)` -- you'd need a `runM :: m a -> a` to get out of that and get a finally correct `MaybeT m b`. That's probably why `MaybeT` is usually defined the [other way round](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html#v:MaybeT) as `m (Maybe a)`.